# UDF при API-запросе

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

С помощью скрипта ниже я получаю балансы по API с биржи CEX.IO.
Проблема заключается в том, что когда я использую этот скрипт в качестве пользовательской функции (UDF), я получаю пустую ячейку.
Но когда я запускаю скрипт вручную, в Logger.log всё отображается корректно. Также с помощью скрипта я могу результат вывести на отдельный лист. Не могу вывести результат используя скрипт как UDF.
Подскажите, что не так?

```
function AUTH() {
  var url = "https://cex.io/api/balance/";
  var nonce = new Date().getTime();
  var user_id = "***";
  var key = "***";
  var secret = "***";
  var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256, nonce.toString()+user_id+key, secret);
  var stringSignature = signature.map(function(byte) {
    return ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }).join('').toUpperCase();

  var params = {
    "method": "post",
    "payload": {
      "key": key,
      "signature": stringSignature,
      "nonce": nonce.toString()
    }
};


  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

//  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
 // var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 // var newActiveSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Лист16");
 //     newActiveSheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(dataAll);

 // return dataAll;
   Logger.log(dataAll);

}
```

В приведенном примере, я получаю правильные значения в Logger.log.
Если использовать часть скрипта, которая закомментирована, я также получу правильные значения в указанной ячейке.

Но если на самом листе в ячейке я укажу `=AUTH()` (при этом Logger.log(dataAll); уходит в комментарии, а return dataAll; снимается с комментирования), то сначала в ячейке появляется "Loading...", что свидетельствует об обработке запроса, а потом ячейка остается пустой.
Как можно было бы использовать данный скрипт в качестве UDF?
Спасибо!

Comment: Что такое "UDF"? Данная аббревиатура не используется в текущем контексте.

Answer (score 1):

Пользовательская фунция не имеет прав на изменение. См. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced

> Read only (can use most get*() methods, but not set*()).

В таком случае вы можете вернуть значение только в текущую ячейку

```
function AUTH() {

  ...

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  return response.getContentText()()
}
```

Вы должны исключить любое упоминание о модификациях Таблиц в функции. И тогда `=AUTH()` будет работать.